# Automation ideas in Microsoft Excel -How to auto-update a manual DB?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, powerquery

Context:

I have a Power Query connected to Salesforce extracting a Sales Report (sheet 1), and an old manually maintained list (sheet 2).

There are many columns in the Sales Report, including Quotation no. and Pillar. In the manual list, there's only Quotation no. and Pillar. Previously, before Power Query was set up, I would manually download the SF report, extract (copy & paste) the data into Excel, and an additional column is used to vlookup the Pillar in the manual list based on Quotation no. Should there be any changes to the Pillar or addition (due to new quotation no.), I would manually update in the manual list (so as to vlookup for the next report).

I would like to automate this process.

I have created a connection to extract Salesforce report and my issue is to automate the update of Pillar name. The idea I have in mind is as follows:

1. Refresh data connection.
2. Pillar name updated based on manually maintained list (automated).
3. Quotation no. with blank pillar name (may not exist in maintained list) updated in sheet 1. OR changes in pillar updated in sheet 1.
4. The changes or addition should be recorded in sheet 2 (so that those that were previously blank will be updated automatically in the next data refresh).
5. Repeat the process.

Note that: There may be addition or removal of Quotation no. with every data refresh.

I have tried to add the Pillar column manually in sheet 1 and entered the Pillar records manually, but it is not dynamic - does not change as data gets refreshed (it should be since it's linked to quotation no.)

Tried the following VBA Code but it's creating duplicated quotation no. in sheet 2 and pillar name does not get updated in sheet 2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim changedCell As Range
Dim manualPillarTable As ListObject
Dim manualPillarColumn As ListColumn
Dim manualPillarRow As ListRow

On Error Resume Next

Set manualPillarTable = Worksheets("ManualPillarData").ListObjects("ManualPillarData")
If manualPillarTable Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set manualPillarColumn = manualPillarTable.ListColumns("Quotation No.")

' Check if the changed cell is in the Pillar column and a new Quotation No.
If Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets("Consulting Opps").ListObjects("Consulting_s_Opportunities_Report_All_mo__2").ListColumns("Pillar").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing And Not IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then
    Set changedCell = Worksheets("Consulting Opps").ListObjects("Consulting_s_Opportunities_Report_All_mo__2").ListColumns("Quotation No.").DataBodyRange.Cells(Target.Row, 1)
    
    ' Find the corresponding row in the ManualPillarData table
    Set manualPillarRow = manualPillarColumn.DataBodyRange.Find(changedCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    ' If the Quotation No. doesn't exist, add a new row to the ManualPillarData table
    If manualPillarRow Is Nothing Then
        Set manualPillarRow = manualPillarTable.ListRows.Add
        manualPillarRow.Range(1, manualPillarColumn.Index).Value = changedCell.Value
    End If
    
    ' Update the Pillar value
    manualPillarRow.ListObject.ListColumns("Pillar").DataBodyRange(manualPillarRow.Index).Value = Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```

Would like to get advise on this. Thanks!

Comment: Start by commenting out the line `On Error Resume Next` and then see what happens when your code runs

Comment: I would start by adding a line at the top of your sub - `If Target.Countlarge > 1 Then Exit Sub` since your code cannot handle multi-cell instances of `Target`